# Capturing a local object in a lambda by reference can cause a data race or not?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-sanitizer, data-race

I have some piece of code that is causing an error when it's run with Thread Sanitizer on:

```
bool Renderer::render(std::optional<int32_t> cancellationToken) {
    const RenderWatcher renderWatcher{cancellationToken};
    ...
    return Render(...
                  [&renderWatcher]() { return !renderWatcher.isRenderInProgress(); });
}
```

Inside `RenderWatcher` I have a constructor that sets the cancellation token in a private field:

```
const std::optional<int32_t> cancellationToken;
```

And some getters:

```
bool RenderWatcher::isRenderInProgress() const {
    if (!cancellationToken) {
        return true;
    }
    ...
}
```

The lambda `[&renderWatcher]() { return !renderWatcher.isRenderInProgress(); }` is a `boost::async` instance stored in a private field and asks about "can this render process be cancelled?".

The TSAN race is in `RenderWatcher` constructor, when setting the cancellationToken, and the `renderWatcher.isRenderInProgress`, which is reading `cancellationToken` without a mutex.

Can I have a data race if RenderWatcher is a local variable but it's captured by reference in the lambda?

Capturing by value solves the race:

```
[renderWatcher]() { return !renderWatcher.isRenderInProgress(); }
```

Or protecting with mutex:

```
bool RenderWatcher::isRenderInProgress() const {
    // Lock mutex here
    if (!cancellationToken) {
        return true;
    }
    ...
}
```

Is this a real data race? How does capturing by reference or by value makes a difference?

Thanks.

Comment: The whole design looks a bit dubious to me, but without seeing a complete example that shows all components of the system, what gets done in what thread, etc, it's a little difficult to say.

Comment: You return a lambda that captures a local reference. Wouldn't that reference be invalid?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. ASAN shows a more clear `stack-use-after-return` violation.